# Recycler view item alignment with header

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-xml, androidx

I have a fragment where the header is aligned to the center of the screen. Since I'm using this header in many fragments, I made it into a separate view and I include it in the different layouts using the `<include>` tag.

Now in a fragment, say Fragment A, I have a `recycler view` and I have the rows in the recycler view which has a `textView` and an `imageView`. They are supposed to be placed horizontally.

```
<ImageView
id="@id/itemImageView"
src="img"
constraintEndToStartOf="@id/itemTextView"
marginEnd="20dp"/>

<TextView
id="@id/itemTextView"
gravity="start ? center"/>
```

I would like the `itemTextView` to be aligned to the `textView in the header`. I am not able to do this exactly in a good manner. I did a hack where I place `the exact textView` from the header inside the `rowView` and make this `textView invisible`. This allows me to make this work, but it doesn't seem very clean or like a hack.

Is there any android thing that I'm missing that allows me to do this?

Comment: means you want itemTextView placed besides textView in the header

Comment: It means the itemTextView should align with the start of the textView. I was able to get a good solution using Guildelines from android for this